# Add bower and npm both in the project , is there a problem about the setting?

Tags: reactjs

I usually use npm to manage my package, nowadays I want to add Bootstrap-duallistbox in my project.However,I read the Guide on github, and it only has details about how to add it with bower.So I would like to know if I add bower.json and package.json at the same time, is there a problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd better don't add them both in your project at the same time.There are some big projects using them both,npm for the backend,like yeoman，grunt，gulp，jshint, bower for the frontend. If you only want to add one package for your project, it's not nessary.